# Don't understand the RunInstaller attribute

Tags: c#, .net, installation, vsto

I need to create a new event source so my office add-in can log events to the event log.  This requires admin rights so I need to do this at installation time.  The msdn docs say:

> If a class that inherits from Installer is marked with the RunInstallerAttribute set to >true, Visual Studio's Custom Action Installer or the InstallUtil.exe will be invoked when >the assembly is installed.

Right now I'm using the standard Visual Studio Outlook 2007 project which I believe creates a ClickOnce setup.exe file which can be used to install my add-in.  So all I need to do is include the MyEventLogInstaller class (shown below) in my add-in project and the setup.exe will detect it and install the log source?  Does my setup.exe detect the RunInstaller attribute and use the 'Custom Action Installer'?  I understand the code(below) but what I don't understand is how the setup program knows to actually call the Install method on the derived MyEventLogInstaller?

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class MyEventLogInstaller: Installer
{
    private EventLogInstaller myEventLogInstaller;

    public MyEventLogInstaller() 
    {
    myEventLogInstaller = new EventLogInstaller();
    myEventLogInstaller.Source = "Source1";
    myEventLogInstaller.Log = "Log1";

    Installers.Add(myEventLogInstaller);   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Got it (I think)!

What I did was create a new Setup Project in Visual Studio 2010.  I then added a new Console Application project to the overarching Solution and added my MyEventLogInstaller class to the Console Application project.  In the main method of the Console Application, I instantiate the MyEventLogInstaller and add some extra code to write to the new event source.  Then I right click on the Setup Project->Add->Assembly... and select the the Console Application executable to add it to the setup project (I'm new to setup projects and I was expecting something more intuitive, but I digress).

Now, the final step (and thanks to [Why won't my Setup Project Perform my Custom Registration Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151003/why-wont-my-setup-project-perform-my-custom-registration-process) for the bit on Custom actions ) is to right click on the setup project, select View->Custom Actions, right click on top level Custom Actions->Add Custom Action..., and select the assembly with the Installer (in my case the Console Application .exe)

After doing all that I can build the .msi and install it with my admin account, and then when I switch back to my non-admin account and run the Console Application, it can now log to the newly created source!! Whew.

Comment: for the last piece what I will try is the bootstrap mainifest generator and generate the output using my .msi, and then hopefully I'll be able to include it as a prerequisite in the ClickOnce