# Visual Studio Setup, Custom Action to copy the setup file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, installation, setup-project, custom-action

I am developing a visual studio setup project. So far all has been good except uninstalling. The program did not create its own uninstaller, but instead the uninstall feature is inside of the setup.msi. So what I need to do is during the install, I need to copy the running setup.msi to the [TARGETDIR]. The easiest way I can think of is to use custom actions. I'm pretty lost on custom actions though, I don't understand where they go and every time I try to code one, its full of errors. Looking at other questions and answers, I have come up with the following:

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class CustomInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
{
    public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver)
    {
        base.Install(stateSaver);
        string path = this.Context.Parameters["targetdir"]; 
        // Do something with path.
    } 
}
```

But I don't understand it. I see how it gets targetdir as that gets passed via the customactiondata. But, RunInstaller isn't known, nor is System.COnfiguration.Install.Installer. Where am I supposed to put this .cs file to make it work? Very confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class should be placed in your application project. I believe it can be included in any project whose DLL is packaged by the setup project, but it usually makes the most sense to put it in the application project.

Make sure your application project references System.Configuration.Install.dll. That will resolve the reference to `Installer`.

`RunInstaller` is in the `System.ComponentModel` namespace (System.dll), so make sure you have a `using System.ComponentModel` statement at the top of the class file.

This question may help you understand custom actions more:

> [Why won't my Setup Project Perform my Custom Registration Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151003/why-wont-my-setup-project-perform-my-custom-registration-process)

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Wait, I can't add just a .cs file. Should I write it in vbs instead?

Comment: If your project is VB and not C# then yes, you can write it in VB. When you add an item to your project there should be an Installer Class template. This will help you get started.

Comment: Then you should be able to add a C# Installer Class. Or, at least a .cs file. Why are you unable to? Make sure you're adding it to your application project, not your setup project.

Comment: Ok I understand I think. So I add the Installer Class and write code. I call that with the custom action. Also would it just be possible to call my main application project but say with an argument of "uninstall" and then have my program do actions if that argument was passed?

Comment: The Installer class has an `Uninstall` method that lets you perform custom actions during an uninstall. Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356160/in-a-visual-studio-setup-project-how-do-i-generate-an-uninstall-script) for how to add the uninstall option to your installer.

Comment: Right, so it does add the application to add/remove list. So you're suggesting I create a batch file that gets dropped into the install directory that contains this line? Also would it be GUID/Programcode of the application?

%windir%\system32\msiexec /x {MY GUID HERE}

Comment: The batch file works but based on that link it looks like there are other options. What is best will probably depend on your situation. And yes, the GUID is the ProductCode from the setup project's property (per the screenshot in the linked question).

Comment: Interesting, I seem to be getting error code 2835, I should check install logs. Hmm, I can't seem to find any.

Comment: [I have one more issue](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55595/discussion-between-kyle-and-keith).

Answer (score 1):

This might help you get started, although it doesn't cover installer classes.

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/getting-started-with-setup-projects/

Error 2835 is a bogus error related to trying to show a dialog, probably the error dialog, so it's masking whatever went wrong, most likely your code.

Make a log using msiexec /I  /l*v  and look for your error before the 2835.

You pass that targetdir value to your custom action like an argument list, so you'd say /targetdir="[TARGETDIR]\" and that's case-sensitive and including the brackets. It's picky because it gets merged with other arguments.

Beware that your code is not running in an application context. It's a call from the msiexec process running with the system account and a working directory of sysetm32. That means full paths need to be specified and any use of a profile-specific item (like Desktop, user profile location) will fail.